# htaccess rewrite rule for a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a custom post type on my Wordpress website called movie. Currently, the post link looks like this: `https://example.com/movie/movie-slug-here`, what I want to have a SEO friendly URL like this one `https://example.com/movie-like-movie-slug-here`. I do not want any redirect, just a rewrite rule.

Here's what I tried but it's not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Rewrite movie-like-the-movie into movie/the-movie 
    RewriteRule ^movies\-like\-(.*)/? movie/$1 [NC]

    # BEGIN WORDPRESS
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WORDPRESS
</IfModule>
```

If I used a 302 redirect it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Custom post type** there should be a name specifying your custom post type. movies with slash and url then custom post name like `https://example.com/movie/movie-slug-here`.

I must say that above URL is already Seo friendly.

If you want URL like `https://example.com/movie-like-movie-slug-here` then you have enter your Custom posts into POSTS Section and choosing permalink in admin setting menu to post-name.
Or you have to enter into pages for that required slug.